# Mysql Select PageId based on count

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by

I am trying to select a page id based on how many comments there are, this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT PageId FROM test.comments  Order By COUNT(Id);
```

How can I just select the pageId's and order them by the amount of rows that contain that page id?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish what you are looking for you need to utilize [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

The GROUP BY statement is used in with aggregate functions to group the result set by one or more columns.

The following query groups every identical page id (ie. based on how many rows contain that page id) and gives you a count of how many times each id repeats:

```
SELECT PageId, COUNT(*) FROM test.comments GROUP BY PageID ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: I need a reputation of 15.